# Move last value to first value

Tags: python, pandas

In this dataframe, I would like to move the value in the last duplicate to the first duplicate and set others to NaT.

```
ID  OutBedTime        DateOutBed
1   16/05/2018 0:17   16/05/2018
1   16/05/2018 4:05   16/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 1:27   17/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 4:41   17/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 4:32   17/05/2018
```

Expected output

```
ID  OutBedTime        DateOutBed    TimeOutBedFinal
1   16/05/2018 0:17   16/05/2018    16/05/2018 4:05
1   16/05/2018 4:05   16/05/2018    NaT
1   17/05/2018 1:27   17/05/2018    17/05/2018 4:32
1   17/05/2018 4:41   17/05/2018    NaT
1   17/05/2018 4:32   17/05/2018    NaT
```

I used this to index the last row:

```
 L = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['DateOutBed'].tail(1)
 L = L.reset_index()['index']
```

But how to assign this value to the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
L1 = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
s1['TimeOutBedFinal'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
```