# Move the value in the second duplicate to the first duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

This post is to assign value of last row to first row: [Move last value to first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62186046/move-last-value-to-first-value).

I would like to move the value in the second duplicate to the first duplicate and set others to NaT.

```
ID  OutBedTime        DateOutBed
1   16/05/2018 0:17   16/05/2018
1   16/05/2018 4:05   16/05/2018
1   16/05/2018 6:05   16/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 1:27   17/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 4:41   17/05/2018
1   17/05/2018 5:32   17/05/2018
```

Expected output

```
ID  OutBedTime        DateOutBed    TimeOutBedFinal
1   16/05/2018 0:17   16/05/2018    16/05/2018 4:05
1   16/05/2018 4:05   16/05/2018    NaT
1   16/05/2018 6:05   16/05/2018    NaT
1   17/05/2018 1:27   17/05/2018    17/05/2018 4:41
1   17/05/2018 4:41   17/05/2018    NaT
1   17/05/2018 5:32   17/05/2018    NaT
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"Move the value in the second duplicate to the first duplicate"* is not pandas idiom. I think you mean *"calculate series, lagged by 1, for each date". Please state what higher-order function you're actually trying to implement, in words? Also, asking near-duplicates is not allowed on SO.

Comment: @smci: this is not my intention. I ask the previous question first and the answer to this question could be generalised to that so nothing agains the rule.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but. as a 10-year user of SO I'm telling you that intentionally posting self-duplicates, esp. shortly after another, is [a clear violation of the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262929/prevent-punish-self-duplicates), so the other asking is likely to be closed as dupe. Anyway, on this one, please do try to explain what more generalizable purpose your code is implementing; there is almost surely a better pandas idiom involving `groupby()`, `diff()` etc.

Comment: @smci: I am just a learner at the beginning level so I do not really understand what is pandas idiom and what is not. I just try my best to write a clear question. If you think it is not appropriate, please help me reword it. Thanks.

Comment: Jason: yes, please do edit the question to reword to state what you're trying to achieve by moving values around. (are you trying to generate a table? summary? reordering the source dataframe for some subsequent calculation? etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `reindex` with `apply` and select the second of row , then do the same as we did from pervious question

```
df['New']=df.groupby('DateOutBed')['OutBedTime'].apply(lambda x : x.iloc[[1]]).reset_index(level=1,drop=True).reindex(df.DateOutBed).values
df['New']=df.New.mask(df.DateOutBed.duplicated())
df
   ID      OutBedTime  DateOutBed             New
0   1  16/05/20180:17  16/05/2018  16/05/20184:05
1   1  16/05/20184:05  16/05/2018             NaN
2   1  16/05/20186:05  16/05/2018             NaN
3   1  17/05/20181:27  17/05/2018  17/05/20184:41
4   1  17/05/20184:41  17/05/2018             NaN
5   1  17/05/20185:32  17/05/2018             NaN
```

Check the update

```
df['New']=df.groupby('DateOutBed')['OutBedTime'].transform(lambda x : x.iloc[1] if len(x)>1 else x.iloc[0])
df['New']=df.New.mask(df.DateOutBed.duplicated())
```

Comment: Thanks but there is an error: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: It works now. Thanks. I modified the codes a bit: M = df.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform(lambda x : x.iloc[1] if len(x)>1 else x.iloc[0])
df['New'] = M.mask(df[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated()).